# Validation on old password field

Tags: jquery

Stucked how to apply validation if old password not entered. Need validation if anyhow user forgot to enter the old password. Thanks in advance.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/hqtbfo8k/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
              validate();
          });
        });

        function validate() {
          var password1 = $("#password1").val();
          var password2 = $("#password2").val();
            if(password1 != password2) {
               $(".error-msg").html("Password and confirmation password do not match.").show();                    
            }
            else {
                $(".error-msg").html("").hide();  
                ValidatePassword();
            }
        }

        function ValidatePassword() {
          var regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/;
          var txt = document.getElementById("password1");
          if (!regex.test(txt.value)) {
              $(".error-msg").html("The password does not meet the password policy requirements.").show();
          } else {
              $(".error-msg").html("").hide();
              window.location.href='change-password-msg.html';
          }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? This seems to be for a password-change form. In general, if the user can't provide the old password, you *shouldn't* consider them validated and shouldn't let them change the password. In any case, please clarify your question and provide a [mcve], along with an explanation of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check first that you `old password input` filled or not. Please see my code may be it can help you. See this live [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtbfo8k/8/)

HTML Code -

```
<div class="error-msg"></div>
<br><br>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>OLD PASSWORD</label>
    <input name="oldPassword" id="oldPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>NEW PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" id="password1" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" id="password2" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE</button>
```

CSS Code -

```
.error-msg {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'nobelregular';
  color: #ff0002;
  display: none;
}
```

JS Code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
    var oldVal = $('#oldPassword').val() || "";
    if (oldVal == "") {
      $(".error-msg").html("First you have to fill Old Password.").show();
      return false;
    }
    validate();
  });
});

function validate() {
  var password1 = $("#password1").val();
  var password2 = $("#password2").val();
  if (password1 != password2) {
    $(".error-msg").html("Password and confirmation password do not match.").show();
  } else {
    $(".error-msg").html("").hide();
    ValidatePassword();
  }
}

function ValidatePassword() {
  var regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/;
  var txt = document.getElementById("password1");
  if (!regex.test(txt.value)) {
    $(".error-msg").html("The password does not meet the password policy requirements.").show();
  } else {
    $(".error-msg").html("").hide();
    window.location.href = 'change-password-msg.html';
  }
}
```

Comment: @AdamPavlov My Pleaseure :)

Comment: if we need the old password check from the db what to do than

Comment: May be this can help you [how can I check my old password with new password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153139/how-can-i-check-my-old-password-with-new-password). @dhS

Comment: Ask your question as new. So, someone can answer that. @dhS

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#old-password").change(function(){
       var value = $("#old-password").val();
     if(value===''){
     alert("please enter Old Password");
     }
      
      });
          $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
              validate();
          });
        });

        function validate() {
         var value = $("#old-password").val();
           if(value===''){
           
           alert("please enter Old Password");
           }
          var password1 = $("#password1").val();
          var password2 = $("#password2").val();
            if(password1 != password2) {
               $(".error-msg").html("Password and confirmation password do not match.").show();                    
            }
            else {
                $(".error-msg").html("").hide();  
                ValidatePassword();
            }
        }

        function ValidatePassword() {
          var regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/;
          var txt = document.getElementById("password1");
          if (!regex.test(txt.value)) {
              $(".error-msg").html("The password does not meet the password policy requirements.").show();
          } else {
              $(".error-msg").html("").hide();
              window.location.href='change-password-msg.html';
          }
        }
```

```css
.error-msg {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'nobelregular';
    color: #ff0002;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error-msg"></div>
<br><br>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>OLD PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" id="old-password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>NEW PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" id="password1" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
    <input type="password" id="password2" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
<button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE</button>
```

you can do validation for old password like this snippet and you can also validate that password using ajax call if you want to validate old password at client side